# Accessing Constants which rely on a list buffer to be populated Scala

Tags: scala, constants, scala-collections, listbuffer

Encountering a problem whereby I am specifying Private Constants at the start of a scala step definiton file which relies on a List Buffer element to be populated, however when compiling I get a 'IndexOutOfBoundsException' because the list is empty initially and only gets populated later in a for loop. 
For Example I have the following 2 constants:

```
private val ConstantVal1= globalExampleList(2)
private val ConstantVal2= globalExampleList(3)
```

globalExampleList is populated further down in the file using a for loop:

```
 for (i <- 1 to numberOfW) {
    globalExampleList += x.xy }
```

This List Buffer adds as many values as required to a global mutable ListBuffer.

Is there a better way to declare these constants? I've tried to declare them after the for loop but then other methods are not able to access these. I have around 4 different methods within the same file which use these values and instead of accessing it via index each time i thought it would be better to declare them as a constant to keep it neat and efficient for whenever they require changing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create list buffer of necessary size with default value and populate it later:

```
val globalExampleList: ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer.fill(numberOfW)(0)

for (i <- 0 until numberOfW) {
  globalExampleList(i) = x.xy 
}
```

But `ConstantVal1`, `ConstantVal2` will still have original default value. So you can make them `var`s and re-assign them after you populate the buffer.

Your code seems to have a lot of mutations and side effects.

Comment: thank you :) is there a better way without the mutations and side effects but still achieve the same result. Im still learning the best way to code in Scala so any info would be great to learn from

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways to go.
First you can use `lazy` modifier

```
private lazy val ConstantVal1= globalExampleList(2)
private lazy val ConstantVal2= globalExampleList(3)
```

Or you can write the two lines after the `for` loop.

```
val globalExampleList = XXXX
for (i <- 1 to numberOfW) { globalExampleList += x.xy }
private val ConstantVal1= globalExampleList(2)
private val ConstantVal2= globalExampleList(3)
```